# Mistake in evaluating $\iint_R \exp(-(x^2+y^2))\,dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to evaluate the integral
$$
\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy
$$
where $R$ is the circular region centered at the origin of radius $2$. I convert to polar coordinates with $x=2\cos\theta$, $y=2\sin\theta$, to get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 e^{-4}r\,dr\,d\theta.
$$
Carrying this out, I get a final answer of $\frac{4\pi}{e^4}$, but apparently the correct answer is $\pi(1-e^{-4})$. I'm pretty sure I evaluated the integral I wrote down correctly, so maybe I have set it up incorrectly? Does anyone see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 e^{-r^2}r\,drd\theta,
$$
because $x^2+y^2=r^2$. (You are interested in the region where $r\le 2$, not in the region where $r=2$.)

The integration with respect to $r$ should be easy. You can probably spot an antiderivative. If not, let $u=r^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the right answer now. Was the mistake taking $x=2\cos\theta$, instead of $x=r\cos\theta$?

Comment: Yes, $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, so $x^2+y^2=r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r^2$.